# Finding K depending upon the following criteria?

Tags: problem-solving, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $\sum_{n=1}^{k}\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{n}{90}\right]=21,$ where $[x]$ denotes the integral part of $x,$ then $k=$

(a) $84$
(b) $80$
(c) $85$
(d) none of these

$21=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{n}{90}\right],$

$=\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{90}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{90}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{59}{90}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{60}{90}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{61}{90}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{k}{90}\right]$

How to proceed next?Any Hint?

Comment: Hint: Calculate the numbers$ [\frac13 + \frac1{90}], [\frac13 + \frac2{90}], ..., [\frac13 + \frac{59}{90}]$. For this, it might be worthwhile to compute $[\frac13 + \frac{60}{90}]$

Comment: upto $\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{90}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{90}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{59}{90}\right]$ = $0$

Comment: Good. And which value do the summands $[\frac13 + \frac{60}{90}]$ up to $[\frac13 + \frac{85}{90}]$ have? Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Marktmeister $\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{60}{90}\right]$ leads to 1.....

Comment: Just to clarify: Is the answer (a), (b), (c) or (d)?

Comment: the ans must be (b)